# Excel formatting numbers to scientific notation when saving as an XML Data

Tags: xml, excel

When working with Excel 2010, I try to save data as an XML Data file. However, some numbers are being formatted to use Scientific notation. For example, the number 0.07 is exported as 7.00000000007E-2 . I checked the cell formatting, and even if the cell is formatted as Text, it is still converted. Also, not all numbers are being formatted.

Hope someone can help with this bizarre issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel is saving the *actual* stored value.  Due to the limited resolution of floating point, the number 7.00000000007E-2 is the nearest possible representation of 0.07 that can be stored in a float.  In other words, it is fundamentally not possible to represent 0.07 *exactly* as a float (probably a double here).

For a good description of the issues, please see the [Wikipedia page on Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply! However, the cell was formatted originally as Currency, so it does not make sense to me that it would be originally stored as a float when it is specifically set to currency. Can you please elaborate as to why this is happening? Also, is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: All numeric data in Excel is stored as floating point unless explicitly made into text (leading apostrophe).  How it is _displayed_ is a completely separate concept.

Answer (score -1):

This issue still persists in 2021, and it apparently only affects the value of .07

Found the solution on the forum linked below. Display your equation the following way:

```
=TEXT(C1-C2,"0.00")
```

where C1 and C2 are cells with data being subtracted (-), and it returns the value at the specified decimal places (this case being 2). Viewing the .xml raw text shows a value of .07

https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1226643-sum-formula-returns-too-many-decimal-places.html